# How to write Mathematical expectation and Probability in the following form

Tags: math-mode, symbols

What commands should I use to type the following operators 
[image: mathematical expectation] and [image: probability] ?

Comment: Could you explain more precise what you are meaning? Like this, it looks like a bad screen-shot of a sans-serif E and P. Maybe bold... What do you need exactly?

Comment: I need mathematical symbols like in this http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Mathematical_expectation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks just like a sans serif font to me. So I would do the following.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\expect}{\mathsf{E}}
\newcommand*{\prob}{\mathsf{P}}

\begin{document}
\[\expect X = \int\displaylimits_{\Omega} X(\omega)\prob}(d\omega)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

- The `\displaylimits` is just used in order to get the first image of your referred homepage. I would leave it away.
- I have not checked, if the new commands are defined by other packages. You could rename them, if you encounter any clash with these.
- `d\omega` would look better as `\mathrm{d}\omega` in my eyes. Matter of taste.

[image]

Comment: perhaps `\DeclareMathOperator`, rather than `\newcommand*`?

Comment: @Bernard One could do that, but I can't see the advantage right know. Could you elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: Finer tuning of horizontal spacing (parentheses and aother delimiters). Most of the time the difference will be infinitesimal, of course. Similarly, there can be spacing problems with `mathrm{d}`, and there a solution from @egreg (don't remember in which thread): `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\d}{\mathop{\kern0pt\mathrm{d}}\!{}}}% `